Laravel send post request
I have a page my.site.ru/tests/edit on this page, I have tests for users.
I have a single deletion of tests, next to each test there is a "Delete" button and when pressed everything happens correctly with a single deletion.
But I also have checkboxes for running several tests and then clicking on the "Delete selected" button I switch to "/tests/massDelete"
and there's a 404 error page error.
Here are my routes :
Here is my controller :
namespace App\\Http\\Controllers;

use Illuminate\\Http\\Request;
use App\\Models\\Test;
use App\\Models\\Question;
use App\\Models\\Answer;
use App\\Models\\Category;
use Auth;

class TestController extends Controller
{
public function index()
{
$tests = Auth::user()-\>tests;
return view('tests.index', compact('tests'));
}

    public function create()
    {
        $categories = Category::all();
        return view('tests.create', compact('categories'));
    }
    
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'description' => 'nullable',
            'duration_hours' => 'required|integer|min:0',
            'duration_minutes' => 'required|integer|min:0',
            'duration_seconds' => 'required|integer|min:0',
            'categories' => 'nullable|array',
            'categories.*' => 'exists:categories,id',
        ]);
    
        $test = new Test();
        $test->title = $request->title;
        $test->description = $request->description;
        $test->user_id = Auth::id();
        $test->duration_hours = $request->duration_hours;
        $test->duration_minutes = $request->duration_minutes;
        $test->duration_seconds = $request->duration_seconds;
        $test->save();
    
        if ($request->has('categories')) {
            $test->categories()->sync($request->categories);
        }
    
        // Обработка вопросов и ответов
        if ($request->has('questions')) {
            foreach ($request->questions as $questionData) {
                $question = new Question();
                $question->test_id = $test->id;
                $question->question = $questionData['question'];
                $question->save();
    
                if (isset($questionData['answers'])) {
                    foreach ($questionData['answers'] as $answerData) {
                        $answer = new Answer();
                        $answer->question_id = $question->id;
                        $answer->answer = $answerData['answer'];
                        $answer->is_correct = $answerData['is_correct'] ?? false;
                        $answer->save();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        return redirect()->route('tests.edit', $test->id);
    }
    
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $test = Test::with('questions.answers', 'categories')->findOrFail($id);
        $categories = Category::all();
        return view('tests.edit', compact('test', 'categories'));
    }
    
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required',
            'description' => 'nullable',
            'duration_hours' => 'required|integer|min:0',
            'duration_minutes' => 'required|integer|min:0',
            'duration_seconds' => 'required|integer|min:0',
            'categories' => 'nullable|array',
            'categories.*' => 'exists:categories,id',
        ]);
    
        $test = Test::findOrFail($id);
        $test->title = $request->title;
        $test->description = $request->description;
        $test->duration_hours = $request->duration_hours;
        $test->duration_minutes = $request->duration_minutes;
        $test->duration_seconds = $request->duration_seconds;
        $test->save();
    
        if ($request->has('categories')) {
            $test->categories()->sync($request->categories);
        }
    
        if ($request->has('questions')) {
            foreach ($request->questions as $questionData) {
                $question = Question::updateOrCreate(
                    ['id' => $questionData['id'] ?? null, 'test_id' => $test->id],
                    ['question' => $questionData['question']]
                );
    
                if (isset($questionData['answers'])) {
                    foreach ($questionData['answers'] as $answerData) {
                        Answer::updateOrCreate(
                            ['id' => $answerData['id'] ?? null, 'question_id' => $question->id],
                            ['answer' => $answerData['answer'], 'is_correct' => $answerData['is_correct'] ?? false]
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        return redirect()->route('tests.index');
    }
    
    
    public function allTests()
    {
        $tests = Auth::user()->tests()->withCount('questions')->get();
        return view('tests.all', compact('tests'));
    }
    
    public function deleteQuestion($id)
    {
        $question = Question::findOrFail($id);
        $question->answers()->delete(); // Удаляем все связанные ответы
        $question->delete(); // Удаляем вопрос
    
        return response()->json(['success' => true]);
    }
    public function delete($id)
    {
        $test = Test::findOrFail($id);
        $test->questions()->delete();
        $test->delete();
        
        return response()->json(['success' => true]);
    }
    
    public function massDelete(Request $request)
    {
        $testIds = $request->input('selected_tests');
        if (!empty($testIds)) {
            foreach ($testIds as $id) {
                $test = Test::findOrFail($id);
                $test->questions()->delete();
                $test->delete();
            }
        }
        return redirect()->route('tests.index');
    }

}

       <h2>
            {{ __('Все тесты') }}
        </h2>
    
    
    <div class="py-12">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div class="bg-white overflow-hidden shadow-sm sm:rounded-lg">
                <div class="p-6 text-gray-900">
                    <form id="delete-tests-form" method="POST" action="{{ route('tests.massDelete') }}">
                        @csrf
                        @method('DELETE')
                        <div class="mb-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="bg-red-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded">
                                Удалить выбранные
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-6">
                            @foreach ($tests as $test)
                                <div class="bg-white shadow-md rounded-lg p-4">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="selected_tests[]" value="{{ $test->id }}" class="mr-2">
                                    <h3 class="text-lg font-semibold mb-2">{{ $test->title }}</h3>
                                    <p class="mt-2 text-gray-600">{{ $test->description }}</p>
                                    <p class="mt-2 text-gray-600">Количество вопросов: {{ $test->questions_count }}</p>
                                    <a href="{{ route('tests.edit', $test->id) }}" class="mt-4 inline-block bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded">
                                        Редактировать
                                    </a>
                                    <button type="button" class="mt-4 inline-block bg-red-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded delete-single" data-id="{{ $test->id }}">
                                        Удалить
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            @endforeach
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
     document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {         document.querySelectorAll('.delete-single').forEach(button =\> {             button.addEventListener('click', function() {                 let testId = this.getAttribute('data-id');                 if (confirm('Вы уверены, что хотите удалить этот тест?')) {                     fetch(\`/tests/${testId}\`, {                         method: 'DELETE',                         headers: {                             'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta\[name="csrf-token"\]').getAttribute('content')                         }                     })                     .then(response =\> response.json())                     .then(data =\> {                         if (data.success) {                             location.reload();                         }                     });                 }             });         });     });  

